# How to create a pointer in C++ that points to a multidumentional array of int?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, int

I know how to create a multidumentional array statndard way:

```
const int m = 12;
const int y = 3;
int sales[y][n];
```

And I know how to create a pointer that points to one dimentional array:

```
int * ms = new int[m];
```

But is it possible to create a pointer that points to multidumentional array?

```
int * sales = new int[y][m];   // doesn't work
int * mSales = new int[m];    // ok
int * ySales = new int[y];    // ok
mSales * ySales = new mSales[y];    // doesn't work, mSales is not a type
```

How to create such a pointer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression `new int[m][n]` creates an `array[m] of array[n] of int`.
Since it's an array new, the return type is converted to a pointer to
the first element: `pointer to array[n] of int`.  Which is what you have
to use:

```
int (*sales)[n] = new int[m][n];
```

Of course, you really shouldn't use array new at all.  The 
_best_solution here is to write a simple `Matrix` class, using
`std::vector` for the memory.  Depending on your feelings on the matter,
you can either overload `operator()( int i, int j )` and use `(i, j)`
for indexing, or you can overload `operator[]( int i )` to return a
helper which defines `operator[]` to do the second indexation.  (Hint:
`operator[]` is defined on `int*`; if you don't want to bother with
bounds checking, etc., `int*` will do the job as the proxy.)

Alternatively, something like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > sales( m, n );
```

will do the job, but in the long term, the `Matrix` class will be worth
it.

Comment: +1 For answering the question and explain why that's not the right solution to the problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9760489/245265 for an example `Matrix` class that wraps a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, it's possible.

You'll be creating a pointer to a pointer to an int, and the syntax is just like it sounds:

```
int** ptr = sales;
```

You've probably seen more examples of this than you think as when people pass arrays of strings (like you do in argv in main()), you always are passing an array of an array of characters.

Of course we'd all prefer using std::string when possible :)

Comment: An array of pointers is not the same as a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 3):

I remember it was something like this:

```
int** array = new int*[m];
for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    array[i] = new int[n];
}
```